# My javascript chews up 100% CPU

Tags: javascript, debugging

So I don't really know why my code is crazy inefficient, and guzzling every spare tick of CPU it can. I don't really know what to do. I'm assuming are some basic tools and techniques for figuring out this kind of problem that are more powerful than commenting out blocks of code and then checking a system monitor.

I tried searching, but all other threads I could find where really specific. I'm hoping to get some answers to the general case of "Damn my javascript is chewing up 100% CPU, ...why?"

-thanks in advance

Comment: It's because of the third line, delete it. if that doesn't help, try format the `c:` local drive

Comment: if it takes 100% it means it's not crashing, nor stoppable. You have to profile your code yourself :-)

But, young padawan, relax, we're here to help! Only if you find the force to give us your code though...

Comment: Try searching "javascript code profiler" in Google and see what comes up. :-)

Comment: Someone upvoted this question. well...

Comment: @gdoron: Ahh, ye got me. Fixing that.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Fire Bug.  From their website:

http://getfirebug.com/javascript

To use the profiler, just go to the Console tab and click the "Profile" button. Then use your app for a bit or reload the page and then click the "Profile" button again. You'll then see a detailed report that shows what functions were called and how much time each one took.

Comment: Pretty much the best answer possible under the questionable circumstances. I'd mention IE's dev tools and Chrome's built in profiler too, just for the sake of completeness.

Comment: Awesome. That was exactly what I needed. For the record. Chrome's dev tools gave me an almost useless reading "95.67% CPU (programe)" where as firebug is

Comment: Thanks that was exactly what I needed. Firebug gave me a specific file and line number. Chrome gave me "(programe)"

Answer (score 0):

You are probably running an endless loop

Edit and yes you can run this in jfiddle, and lock up the window becase it will run inside the loop forever.

Go to http://jsfiddle.net/ and run

```
i = 0;
while(true) { i++; }
```

Comment: @gdoron: I realized I couldn't and so deleted my comment. :-)